# How to change the kernel name in Jupyter Notebook running on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am experienced Python/Jupyter user, but a Windows newbie, after downloading and installing Anaconda Python 3 distribution and firing up a Jupyter notebook I noticed that the kernel for the Jupyter Notebook says `Python[Root]` (instead of `Python 3` on Unix-based systems).

Notebook works fine, but sharing notebooks seems to be problematic as whenever a notebook created on my machine is opened on a non-Windows machine the user encounters a "cannot find `Python[Root]` kernel" message and is prompted to select Python 3 (or Python 2) kernel.  This is annoying.

I do not seem to have the option of changing the kernel manually within the notebook. Perhaps this is an issue with how Anaconda (or Jupyter) is installed on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nb_conda_kernels package is not used (as in this case), the name of the kernel is taken from the kernel spec file. To find the the kernel spec use `jupyter kernelspec list` command:

```
(base) C:\Users\user>jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2    C:\Anaconda2\share\jupyter\kernels\python2
```

For each kernel there will be kernel.json file in the corresponding folder, where **display_name** can be changed:

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2", 
 "language": "python", 
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Anaconda2\\python.exe", 
  "-m", 
  "ipykernel_launcher", 
  "-f", 
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

In my case it's a Python 2 environment, but the format is the same for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Anaconda's virtual environments'. The "Root" kernel that you see is from Anaconda's environment that is created upon installation. In order to install other kernels for various versions of python see http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html.

Comment: Is this root kernel only created on windows? I have used Jupiter extensively on Linux and OS X and the kernel has always been either Python 3 or 2 by default. Are you suggesting that I install another Python 3 kernel in addition to the default Python 3 root kernel?